# Background repeat will cause the image to repeat in a weird way

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a body background image which would repeat itself. Sadly the image repeats in a weird way, as you can see on the following site: [Link to the background image](http://pr0b.com/)

My css code looks like the following:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("../img/background.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

What am i doing wrong that the image would repeat in this way:

[image]

Comment: This is the problem of image only. Try to get a better image. It's not symmetric image

Comment: The upper part of the image is a different color than the bottom.

Comment: @HerrSerker Sarcasm of that nature is not needed here. [Be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: If i use this image as a background image: http://pr0b.com/assets/img/background_big.png wouldnt it take long to load up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upper part of the image is different than the bottom.

You should use a very small image and repeat that.
Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRrIb.png

It might be wiser to use a data/uri, rather than an image, this way you won't have to host it.

Here's an example as per your image: [Demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/417acf6u/)

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAIAgMAAAC5YVYYAAAADFBMVEUBupkBlHoBlXoClXqzJdbeAAAAIElEQVQI12NgCGVgnsLAmsAg2sBQzcCwhZEhgZPhgBgALyMEVqftfRkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!